# get_post_meta fails after switch_to_blog

Tags: multisite, post-meta

I have some code for custom cron in wordpress multisite, that from each blog site, gets their posts and postmeta data and put them on an xml structure.

But, when I retrive metadata (using `get_post_meta`) from each blog (using `switch_to_blog`), I get the data from the principal site (blog_id=1) not from the site I would like (for instance blog_id=33)

This is an example of part of my code:

```
function generate_xml(33);

function generate_xml($blog_id){
global $wpdb;

$change_ok = switch_to_blog($blog_id);
if ( is_wp_error($change_ok) ) {
    WriteErrorLog($change_ok->get_error_message());
}
else {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data></data>', null, false);
    $Body = $xml->addChild('Body');
    $add_adverts = $Body->addChild('add_adverts');

    $sql_posts = "select id, post_title, post_content from wp_".$blog_id."_posts where post_type = 'custom_add' and post_status = 'publish'";
    $result_posts = $wpdb->get_results ($sql_posts);
    foreach ( $result_posts as $data_posts ){
        $post_id_loop = $data_posts->id;
        $advert  = $add_adverts->addChild('advert');
        //...
        $price = get_post_meta($post_id_loop, '_price', true);
        $advert->addChild('price', $price);
        $color = get_post_meta($post_id_loop, '_color', true);
        $advert->addChild('color', $color);
        $size = get_post_meta($post_id_loop, '_size', true);
        $advert->addChild('size', $size);
        //...
    }
}
//... more code
restore_current_blog();
```

}

A summary of the data in the database tables is this:

[image: Example:]

But, the data I get are these:

[image]

How can I use `get_post_meta()` on each site blog after do it `switch_to_blog()`?

Comment: After `$add_adverts = $Body->addChild('add_adverts');`, add `echo $blog_id;` and check if 33 is outputted. EDIT: Also, blog id 1 would have table `wp_posts` and 2 has `wp_2_posts` so you need to adjust your code accordingly in case you want to use this function for blog with ID 1. Just a note.

Comment: I do it and echo show me the blog_id is 33. Even using the method who tell me in wich blog I am `echo get_current_blog_id();`. The reason to use  `get_post_meta` is to avoid using `$sql = "select meta_value from wp_".$blog_id."_postmeta where post_id=".$blog_id;
 $result = $wpdb->get_results ($sql); ....etc.`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `$wpdb` to get your posts instead of using [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)?

Comment: I'm not used to using `get_posts()`. Can I filter, for example by post-type and/or post-status?

Comment: Yes you can, please see documentation.

Comment: Well, I changed the way of retrive post, using `get_posts()`, and now it gets post from the principal site (blog_id=1). I don't know why it happens, but I think it can be a wordpress bug

Answer (score 0):

reading through your code ...

```
if ( is_wp_error($change_ok) ) {
    WriteErrorLog($change_ok->get_error_message());
}
```

is not applicable as $change_ok will always be true. ref  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog

as the comments state it is better to use get_posts() and this may fix your issue, otherwise use $wpdb->prepare before your get_results.

also a comment is that your SQL statement will not work for the primary site..
`$sql_posts = "select id, post_title, post_content from wp_".$blog_id."_posts where post_type = 'custom_add' and post_status = 'publish'";`

A note is that the "wp_" table prefix can be changed in the wp-config.php file and if a site has done the "wp_" hardcoded prefix would never work the `$wpdb->base_prefix` can be used to make the "wp_" always fit the current site.
also the `wp_".$blog_id."_posts` is not going to work for the main site as the table structure is different

a simple function to get the current site WP database table prefix...

```
// Get the database prefix
function get_blog_prefix( $blog_id=null ) {

    global $wpdb;

    if ( null === $blog_id ) {
        $blog_id = $wpdb->blogid;
    }
    $blog_id = (int) $blog_id;

    if ( defined( 'MULTISITE' ) && ( 0 == $blog_id || 1 == $blog_id ) ) {
        return $wpdb->base_prefix;
    } else {
        return $wpdb->base_prefix . $blog_id . '_';
    }
}
```